Function app unit testing with GetInput and data repository return not working
When running a unit test, it does not seem to continue through the repo/data return to continue processing and just fast forwards to the return.  The gist of the code is:
namespace program
{
    [FunctionName("Processor")]
    public static async Task<Boolean> Processor([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        var eventDetails =  context.GetInput<entitydataobject>();
        IRepoData repo = null;
        List<Guid> list;
        try
        {
            repo = Repository();
            list = repo.GetEntityList(Guid.Parse(entitydataobject.Guid), entitydataobject.Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("Processor Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
    public static IRepoData Repository() 
    {
        try
        {
            return new RepoData("Data Source=instance.local;Initial Catalog=database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Repository Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

The gist of the Unit Test:
namespace Test 
{ 
    [TestClass] 
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] 
    public class ProcessorTests 
    {
        var mockContext = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContest>();      
        var inputData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<entitydataobject>(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));      
        var list = new List<Guid>();      
        var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();      
        var log = new Mock<ILogger>();       
        list.Add(new Guid());      
        list.Add(new Guid());       
        repository.Setup(repo => repo.GetEntityIdList(Guid.Parse("4D47AF6C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "string").Returns(list);      
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.GetInput<entitydataobject>()).Returns(entitydataobject); 
        var result = program.Processor(context.Object, log.Object);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Result);                
    }
}

My guess is that the repository setup is not passing through.
I tried to execute in VS 2022, and it progresses up to the point of repository/GetEntityList, but just skips over it/does not populate the list.

Can you share your complete code in the question?

I tried your code and got the same error , the issues with the GetEntityList method inside your unit test.
Update the Processor Method:
Processor to await asynchronous methods .Use async repository method to avoid blocking threads
  public static async Task<Boolean> ProcessEntity([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            var eventDetails = context.GetInput<entitydataobject>();
            IRepoData repo = null;
            List<Guid> list;

            try
            {
                repo = Repository();

                list = await Task.Run(() => repo.GetEntityList(Guid.Parse(eventDetails.Guid), eventDetails.Name));
                if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError("Processor Error: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static IRepoData Repository()
        {
            try
            {
                return new RepoData("Server=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Repository Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }


Update the Unit test :
The IRepoData interface and its implementation (RepoData) have been refactored to be asynchronous, using Task<List<Guid>>.The unit test uses await to handle the asynchronous nature of Processor. The repository mock now returns a Task using .ReturnsAsync(list).
public class ProcessorTests
        {
            private readonly IDurableOrchestrationContext _context;
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
            private readonly IRepoData _repo;

            private readonly entitydataobject _validEntityDataObject;
            private readonly List<Guid> _entityList;

            public ProcessorTests()
            {
                _context = Substitute.For<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
                _logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
                _repo = Substitute.For<IRepoData>();
                _validEntityDataObject = new entitydataobject
                {
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Name = "SampleName"
                };

                _entityList = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

                _context.GetInput<entitydataobject>().Returns(_validEntityDataObject);
            }

            [Fact]
            public async Task ProcessEntity_ShouldReturnTrue_WhenDataIsProcessedSuccessfully()
            {
                _repo.GetEntityList(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(_entityList);

                var result = await Processor.ProcessEntity(_context, _logger);




